# camel blueprint test not working with sql named parameters in sql.properties

Tags: java, sql, testing, apache-camel, blueprint

Can any one suggest some solution for the below scenarios

1. I have query(select id  from emp.employee) to get Id from tblemployee.

its working and I am getting the value

1. Inside second query and passing the id value after setting to header as named parameter like.
2. select * from emp.address where empid=:#id

its working fine when I am  I writing blueprint test its 
showing below exception

> ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId:
>   ID-BLRKEC329635D-62313-1435237232679-0-3 on ExchangeId:
>   ID-BLRKEC329635D-62313-1435237232679-0-2). Exhausted after delivery
>   attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception
>   occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: [{id=2}]]

the header values are also printing in the exchange like

### Exchange

Exchange[
    Id                  ID-BLRKEC329635D-62313-1435237232679-0-2
    ExchangePattern     InOnly
    Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-BLRKEC329635D-62313-1435237232679-0-1, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, CamelSqlRowCount=1, firedTime=Thu Jun 25 18:30:34 IST 2015, id=2}
    BodyType            java.util.ArrayList
    Body                [{id=2}]
]

### Stacktrace

> org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during
>   execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: [{id=2}]]